# Know which collection contains me!

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, binding

in my Silverlight 4 project, I have a simple class implementing the interface like:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
  string Name { get; set; }
  anyotherclass Value { get; set; }
}
```

a parent class contains a collection of IMyClass elements like:

```
public class ParentClass
{
  ObservableCollection<IMyClass> Children { get; }
}
```

Now I want to make sure, that IMyClass.Name is unique in the Children collection. The user can change the IMyClass.Name - so I need to validate if the name is already in the collection. I want to use the Silverlight exception and validation mechanism, my XAML-textbox looks like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding 
                ValidatesOnExceptions=true,
                NotifyOnValidationError=true,
                Mode=TwoWay,
                Path=Name}"/>
```

So I need to check in the setter of the Name property like:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set 
    {
        if (value == _name)
            return;

        if (CollectionAlreadyContainsName(this, value))
            throw new ArgumentException("The name already exists");
        else
            _name = value;

        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

And here comes the problem: CollectionAlreadyContainsName needs to know the collection, but in an IMyClass-object I do not know in which collection I am. I would need to keep a reference to the parent like

```
public interface IMyClass
{
  string Name { get; set; }
  anyotherclass Value { get; set; }
  ParentClass Parent { get; }
}
```

which tastes bad to me because of cross referencing and the need to asure that the parent is always set properly. So I look for another way to do this. One idea was to let the ParentClass listen to a NameChanged-event of IMyClass and reverting the name change if necessary. But this would not work with the mentioned Silverlight exception and validation mechanism.

Any ideas how to address this?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving the IMyClass the wrong responsibility. It doesn't know about the collection and it shouldn't.

It is the responsibility of the collection class to only add objects that differ in name.

So override/create an add method that does this and either make the name readonly or subscribe to the change of the name in the collection and throw an error there.

**EDIT**

Do not revert the property. That is not the responsibility of the collection.

Comment: Using the Silverlight validation and exception mechanism, I need (as far as I know) to validate the entry in the setter and raise an Exception, if something is wrong - like there is already another object with the given name in the containing list. I would like to keep to that mechanism of informing the user that the input is wrong, because it is already build in and easy to implement (it's just the throw in the setter and two properties at the user control :) )

Comment: i understand but disagree. The class should know about the collection. You could  add validation to the collection. The fact that validation in SL works this way is not a good excuse to mess up responsibilities. It is up to you of course. Just my 2c.

Comment: I totally agree with you about that. The data binding should somehow work with a validation mechanism of the collection like: User Input -> Collection validates -> propagate the user input to the object or throw an exception. Unfortunately, this behavior isn't build in in SL (as far as I know) and implementing manually would cause a lot of overhead, which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that it isn't that simple; an object can be referenced by zero, one or *many, many* collections. Assuming that there is a good OO reason for the child to know about the parent (which is actually pretty rare), you need to decide which it is you need to support. I wouldn't use events here as events are *also* multicast, potentially confusing things.

If it is a strong parent/child relationship, then by all means *add* a parent property, but you should enforce it - i.e. you can't accidentally add an object that is already a child of another collection, and adding it should set the parent.

You should also ensure that there is only one Add api - i.e. do you call a method on the object? or on the collection? either works, but having one method will save confusion. You will almost certainly need a custom collection to do this, to avoid the default Add implementation.

Comment: I already feared, that it isn't that simple *g*. The main reason for wanting to check the integrity in the name-setter is to use the Silverlight validation and exception mechanism, which provides an easy and nice way to check the entry and return feedback to the user. Another problem is, that the user is allowed to change the name afterwards, so simply "controlling" the add-method(s) would not be enough. Beside making good OO, I try to not over-engineer and use as many (good working) standard methods/classes as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `Parent` property in the interface, just a data member in the implementing class. Pass the parent to the constructor.

Comment: That would be possible, but I forgot to tell you about the XML-Serialization, which requires a parameterless constructor and public setter properties for the deserialization. (And it still is kind of cross referencing)